# "Uncaught TypeError: XLSX.read is not a function" when using SheetJS

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, sheetjs

I have used SheetJS js-xlsx library to load data from xlsx file into Fiori grid view. App is working when I run it using the SAP Hana Web IDE. Then I have deployed app to the Hana Cockpit and Register the app in Fiori LaunchPad as follows:

[image: Deployed app using the web IDE as follows:]

The first time it will show the excel data but from the second time onwards it shows a Javascript error "XLSX.read undefined".

[image: Open active version of the application - works the code]

[image: Open the registered application in Launchpad - app will not work]

And sows the following error:

[image: Javascript error]